# Static variable returns null when returning to the app

Tags: android

I have two activitys the first one is LoginActivity where I have this five static variables:

```
public static Login loginTargetApp;
public static Gateway gateway;
public static Login loginGateway;
public static OfflineUser offlineUser;
public static boolean isLoggedIn;
```

In my second activity, MainViewActivity, when I try to acess this variables after android destroyed and reacreated my activity it returns null and the app crashes:

```
jsonTempDownload = new File(Constants.DEST_PATH_PARENT + File.separator
                    + LoginActivity.gateway.getUuidInstituicao() + Constants.JSON_TEMP_DOWNLOAD);
```

I'm trying to save variable states doing:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle saveInstanceState) {

    saveInstanceState.putParcelable("loginTargetApp", LoginActivity.loginTargetApp);
    saveInstanceState.putParcelable("gateway", LoginActivity.gateway);
    saveInstanceState.putParcelable("loginGateway", LoginActivity.loginGateway);
    saveInstanceState.putParcelable("offlineUser", LoginActivity.offlineUser);

    saveInstanceState.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", LoginActivity.isLoggedIn);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(saveInstanceState);
}
```

To recover my variable values I've tried two different ways, but they didn't work:

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    LoginActivity.loginTargetApp = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("loginTargetApp");
    LoginActivity.gateway = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("gateway");
    LoginActivity.loginGateway = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("loginGateway");
    LoginActivity.offlineUser = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("offlineUser");

    LoginActivity.isLoggedIn = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isLoggedIn");

}
```

and:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.d(Constants.MAIN_VIEW_ACTIVITY, "----------------");
        Log.d(Constants.MAIN_VIEW_ACTIVITY, "Abrindo MainViewActivity...");
        Log.d(Constants.MAIN_VIEW_ACTIVITY, "----------------");

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {

            // Restore value of members from saved state

            LoginActivity.isLoggedIn = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isLoggedIn");
            boolean isLoggedIn = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isLoggedIn");
            Log.d(Constants.MAIN_VIEW_ACTIVITY, "VARIÁVEL NORMAL: " + isLoggedIn);
            Log.d(Constants.MAIN_VIEW_ACTIVITY, "VARIÁVEL ESTÁTICA: " + LoginActivity.isLoggedIn);

            LoginActivity.loginTargetApp = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("loginTargetApp");
            Login loginTargetApp = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("loginTargetApp");
            Log.d(Constants.MAIN_VIEW_ACTIVITY, "VARIÁVEL NORMAL: " + loginTargetApp.getEmailAndress());
            Log.d(Constants.MAIN_VIEW_ACTIVITY, "VARIÁVEL ESTÁTICA: " + LoginActivity.loginTargetApp.getEmailAndress());

            LoginActivity.gateway = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("gateway");
            LoginActivity.loginGateway = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("loginGateway");

            LoginActivity.offlineUser = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("offlineUser");
            OfflineUser offlineUser = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("offlineUser");
            Log.d(Constants.MAIN_VIEW_ACTIVITY, "VARIÁVEL NORMAL: " + offlineUser.getEmail());
            Log.d(Constants.MAIN_VIEW_ACTIVITY, "VARIÁVEL ESTÁTICA: " + LoginActivity.offlineUser.getEmail());

        } else {

            Log.d(Constants.MAIN_VIEW_ACTIVITY, "SAVED INSTANCE STATE IS NULL");
        }
```

In onCreate method my savedInstance is not null but when I try to show the values in Log.d, it's still crashing.

Comment: when activity is destroyed and recreated your static variables are re-initialized

Comment: but I'm saving it's states in saveInstanceState and reassigning in onRestoreInstanceState.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of points:

1- `static` is not `final` and therefore can be null, in other words, make sure you are setting those values to something.

2- `super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);` should be called at the start of `protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` not end of it.

[Source (Look at the end of the page)](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

Let me know, cheers.

Comment: You were right, I was doing something wrong trying to get values that was never instantiated, Thanks bro